# ArrayFormula dosent spread to the entire colum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to create an ArrayFormula that will spread to the entire column that will get date info from the sheet it's in 'Circulation' and will compare it to date info in a different sheet called 'Meetings'
if the month=month and year=year it will get the number from j column.
now the code works without ArrayFormula just doesn't spread to the entire column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pjdy3Ywa556aZS3k8euJYyd9d-IR7qVsBKFu7luEQwA/edit?usp=sharing  (Circulation sheet- B column.)

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(Meetings!J2:J,Meetings!H2:H=true,MONTH(Meetings!I2:I)=MONTH(A2:A),YEAR(Meetings!I2:I)=YEAR(A2:A)),"0"))*15000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A2:A), TO_TEXT(QUERY(Meetings!I:J, 
 "select I,sum(J) where I is not null group by I label sum(J)''", 0)), 2, 0))*15000)
```

[image: 0]